# If T ◦ S = S ◦ T and v is an eigenvector of T, then v is an eigenvector of S

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have to prove or provide a counterexample to the following claim:
 Let $V$ be a vector space, $T, S : V \to V$ linear transformations. If $T S = ST$ and $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$, then $v$ is an eigenvector of $S$.

I thought it's correct and started to prove it,
I showed that $S(v)$ is an eigenvector of $T$, but I got stuck there.

$S(T(v)) = T(S(v))$
$S(\lambda v)=T(S(v))$
$\lambda S(v)=T(S(v))$

Comment: You don't say that $S = 0$ is disallowed...

Comment: It is allowed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $T$ as the identity map and $S$ as any linear map. Then clearly $TS=ST$. If the proposition were true, then every eigenvector of $T$ would be an eigenvector of $S$. But since $T$ is identity, *every* vector of $V$ is an eigenvector of $T$. So as soon as one finds an $S$ for which some vector is not an eigenvector we have disproved the proposition. Of course, there are many such examples of $S$.